# Whats wrong with the syntax in my mysql select statement (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table and i'm trying to extract the maximum value of a column called order_num, which has 33 intries of integers 1 through 33.  I want the value "33" in this instance as its the highest number.

$userid is an integer derived from a one row table with a field id that I am trying to retrieve

```
//get the currentUser ID so we know whos deck to ammend
$userIDSQL = "SELECT id FROM currentUser";
$userIdResult = mysqli_query($db, $userIDSQL) or die("SQL Error on fetching user ID: " . mysqli_error($db));

$result_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userIdResult)) {
    $result_array[] = $row['id'];
}

//the actual user id
$userId = $row['id'];
echo "user id is " . $userId;
```

Doing a print_r on $userId shows the array to be empty, that's why the code below doesn't work.. :(

...

```
$reOrderDeckSQL = "SELECT MAX(order_num) AS order_num FROM decks WHERE id='$userId'";
$reOrderDeckResult = mysqli_query($db, $reOrderDeckSQL) or die("SQL Error on reOrder: " . mysqli_error($db));

        $result_array = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reOrderDeckResult)) {
            $result_array[] = $row['MAX(order_num)'];
            echo "the result is" . $result_array['order_num'];
            echo "the result is" . $row['order_num'];
            echo "the result is" . $result_array['MAX(order_num)']; //tried different methods to get the output.
        }
```

The output I get is

```
the result is  the result is  the result is
```

Does anyone know why i'm not able to get the result from the table?

Comment: try `$result_array = $row['MAX(order_num)'];` - you're currently adding the row as a new element in `$result_array` - if you want to do that, I think you'll need to echo `$result_array[0]['order_num'];`

Comment: i wonder why `$row['order_num']` doesn't print anything, maybe the `$userId` have no recors?

Comment: use the alias you have created as index of your $row array

Comment: Maybe just try to give it a different alias from its actual name? `MAX(order_num) AS total` and print with `$row['total']`

Comment: I suspect there is just no rows for the given userId. In your question you refer to both `$user_id` and `$userId` so maybe that's the issue.

Comment: user_id was a typo, fixed.

Comment: Its working now I got rid of the while loops and got rid of the arrays. 
`$userId = $row['id'];
echo "<br>user id is " . $userId; // $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reOrderDeckResult);
            echo"<br>"; print_r($row);`

Comment: try print_r on $result_array[]. Btw, why are you populating an array with your user IDs? If the current user is only 1 person, you dont need an array for 1 value.
This part pushes your id into an array. `$result_array[] = $row['id'];`  . Here `$userId = $row['id'];` you are outside of the while loop, so your `$userId` never gets a value. Move this: `$userId = $row['id'];` inside your while loop, and get rid of this: `$result_array[] = $row['id'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code to get the userId doesn't work because of your usage of the array, change to:

```
$userId = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userIdResult)) {
    $userId = $row['id'];
}
```

As I've shown below, if you only expect a single row then remove the while loop and just call `fetch_assoc` a single time.

Given you only want the single row you don't need the while loop:

```
$reOrderDeckSQL = "SELECT MAX(order_num) AS order_num FROM decks WHERE id='$userId' LIMIT 1";
$reOrderDeckResult = mysqli_query($db, $reOrderDeckSQL) or die("SQL Error on reOrder: " . mysqli_error($db));

if($reOrderDeckResult && mysqli_num_rows($reOrderDeckResult) == 1)
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reOrderDeckResult);
    echo 'result: ' . $row['order_num'];
}
else
{
    echo 'No rows found!!';
}
```

I also added `LIMIT 1` to the query, and a check to see if there are any rows.

Comment: Don't you mean `$row['order_num']`?

Comment: Getting rid of the while loops and arrays fixed it for me, so I'll mark this as best answer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: In addition, the next thing im trying to do is add one to the result of the max number and then store it to a variable  I do `$newOrder = ((int) $row) + 1;
        echo "<br> new order is: " . $newOrder;` but the result is "1" and it should be "34" any ideas?

Comment: I think it should be `$newOrder = ((int) $row['order_num']) + 1; echo "<br> new order is: " . $newOrder;` That should work if you do it after the fetch assoc call.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

Okay, try this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reOrderDeckResult)) {
   print_r($row);
}
```

What do you get?

Comment: Sorry, i'm quite new to this and i'm not sure what you mean by your last answer print_r would have saved me what?  how can I do that?

Comment: first of all, the php manual tells you how to use functions, so if you don't know what one does, the first thing you should do it look it up. print_r() shows you exactly what an array contains.

Comment: It's empty! :( Must be a problem with $userID like someone said above.. Sorry for leading you up the garden path.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me find the answer to the problem.

Comment: You're welcome, sorry it wasn't more clear before. BTW, you should do some reading on MySQL JOINS.

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you..,

```
<?php

$reOrderDeckSQL = "SELECT MAX(order_num) AS order_num FROM decks WHERE id='$userId'";
$reOrderDeckResult = mysqli_query($db, $reOrderDeckSQL) or die("SQL Error on reOrder: " . mysqli_error($db));

$result_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reOrderDeckResult)) {

   //you have to use the alias name not aggregate function title
    $result_array[] = $row['order_num'];

    echo "the result is" . $result_array['order_num'];
    echo "the result is" . $row['order_num'];

    //you have to use the alias name not aggregate function title
    echo "the result is" . $result_array['order_num']; //tried different methods to get the output.
}
```

Comment: Could you add some description of what you've changed?

Answer (score 0):

You have renamed your `MAX(order_num) AS order_num` so you should try to get value using  `order_num` only as `echo $result_array['order_num']`

and in while you should check whether you are getting value or not by placing below code in while loop

```
echo '<PRE>';
print_r($row);
echo '</PRE>';
```

Comment: if (!$reOrderDeckResult) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}else{ while loop }